# Show navbar menu depends on user authentication

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a fixed navbar component in different views.

This navbar contain **Login** link which redirect to **login page**.

After the user enter his correct credentials I redirect him to home page which contain the same navbar.

> What I am trying to do:

Change the **Login** link in the navbar with **Logout** link and show the user name near it. *(e.g. welcome, Adam)*

> What I have tried to do in the Navbar Component:

```
    <template>
  <header>
    <div v-if="logged_in" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12  text-center text-sm-right">
      <!-- header top menu -->
      <div class="header-top-menu">
        <ul>
          <li>
            Welcome, {{ user.name }}
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" @click="logout">
              Logout
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- end of header top menu -->
    </div>
    <div v-else class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12  text-center text-sm-right">
      <!-- header top menu -->
      <div class="header-top-menu">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <router-link :to="{name: 'Login'}">
              Login
            </router-link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <router-link :to="{name: 'Register'}">
              Register
            </router-link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- end of header top menu -->
    </div>
  </header>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      user: null,
      logged_in: false,
    }),
    methods: {
      logout () {
        this.$store.dispatch('logout').then((res) => {
          this.user = null;
          this.logged_in = false;
          this.$router.push({ name: 'Login'});
        });
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.$store.dispatch('userDetails').then(() => {
        this.user = this.$store.getters.getUserDetails;
        this.logged_in = true;
      });
    },
  }
</script>
```

> Problem and conclusion:

After the user login I need to refresh the home page to load the user info because, I am using `created()` function.

I think I should use ***computed property*** or ***watch*** but I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Your navbar should probably not manage the login action. I would set a `prop` on the navbar:

```
props: {
    logged_in: Boolean
}
```

so that your `v-if's` work whenever its value is changes. And I would restructure your logic such that login and logout are performed externally to your component, via emits:

```
<a v-if="logged_in" v-on:click="$emit('logout')">Logout</a>
<a v-if="!logged_in" v-on:click="$emit('login')">Login</a>
```

Then external to your component you can direct the appropriate methods and update the `loggin_in` property:

```
v-on:logout="do_logout_method()"
v-on:login="do_login_method()"
```

Comment: So where should I manage the login action if not in the navbar?